# MarkLogic - using single transaction with REST and XCC

Tags: marklogic

Is it possible to create a transaction with XCC and use the transaction id with the RestAPI calls?

I've made an application that does that, but sometimes I'm getting a "no transaction" error. It's strange, because most of the calls succeed.

edit:

I couldn't find anything in documentation regarding this.

Comment: I can't picture why you'd want to do that (instead of using the REST API to create the transactions), but could you show the code you've tried that produces the error? We're more likely to be able to spot the problem that way.

Comment: Also, please let us know what version of MarkLogic you're using

Comment: I can see a purpose for that if you are trying to span transactions across XCC as well as REST api calls. Though, with latest REST api changes, you should be able to do most with just REST api, potentially leveraging libraries like Java Client API as well.

Comment: Have you checked for errors? Server-side or client-side errors might be causing transactions to get closed earlier than you expect..

Comment: Assuming that you have multiple MarkLogic nodes, are you ensuring that the requests are all going to the same host and appserver? The transaction is only valid on the node that you create it. Making a request to one of the other nodes will result in a "no transaction" error.